# SQL - work data from a different column in same view

Tags: sql

I have this View in SQL:

```
Table Name: cars
+----------+
| Car_Type |
+----------+
| volvo    |
| tesla    |
| audi     |
+----------+
```

I get the Car type using a Left join. 
Now I want to a the column `isElectric` with the an SQL CASE statement to know if an car is electric

My code is hardcoded in the view when the new column is added:

```
CASE 
  WHEN cars.Car_Type = 'volvo' THEN cars.isElectric=0
  WHEN cars.Car_Type = 'tesla' THEN cars.isElectric=1
  WHEN cars.Car_Type = 'audi' THEN cars.horsepower=0
END
```

I want to have the following output:

```
+----------+-----------+
| Car_Type | isElectric|
+----------+-----------+
| volvo    | 0         |
| tesla    | 1         |
| audi     | 0         |
+----------+-----------+
```

Unfortunately this does not work, does anyone know how to fix this? 
Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: your expected output

Comment: Why are you trying to equate the column to something? You can only do that in update statements. Selects are just projections.

Comment: Those isElectric values should be stored in the table!

Comment: @jarlh unfortunately I can't store them in a table (bad architecture)

Comment: Do you expect the programmers to know such facts if a car is electric or not? When a BMW is added to the table, do you expect the applications to be rewritten?!? Fix the data model!

Comment: @jarlh is is a proxy example for a difficult problem, the programmer do not know what isElectric is, it is determand right when the view gets created

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: `WHEN cars.Car_Type = 'volvo' THEN 0 .. end as isElectric`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want the provided values to be selected as the horsepower. If the values are contained in the cars table you don't need a CASE - WHEN just select the horsepower column from the cars table.

```
CASE 
  WHEN cars.Car_Type = 'volvo' THEN 150
  WHEN cars.Car_Type = 'tesla' THEN 300
  WHEN cars.Car_Type = 'audi' THEN 187
END AS Horsepower
```

Updating for your update:

```
CASE 
  WHEN cars.Car_Type = 'volvo' THEN 0
  WHEN cars.Car_Type = 'tesla' THEN 1
  WHEN cars.Car_Type = 'audi' THEN 0
END AS IsElectric
```

You can also do it whit a CASE - WHEN - ELSE because you only select 0 or 1

Comment: maybe hoursepower is a bad example, I changed my question

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to express this?

```
(CASE WHEN cars.Car_Type = 'volvo' THEN 0
      WHEN cars.Car_Type = 'tesla' THEN 1
      WHEN cars.Car_Type = 'audi' AND crs.horsepower = 0 THEN 1
      WHEN cars.Car_Type = 'audi' THEN 0
 END) as isElectric
```